# Incrementing a local variable using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, local, counter, increment

I am trying to increment a counter, but I would like to move the variable out of the global namespace and declare it locally. I'm not sure how to do this. Thanks for your help.

This is the code I'm using at the moment.

```
var mediaClickCounter = 0;
function refreshMediaAds() {
    if (mediaClickCounter < 2) {
        mediaClickCounter++;
    } else {
        mediaClickCounter = 0;
        refreshAds();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
// the function creates a local scope. 
var refreshMediaAds = (function() { 
    var mediaClickCounter = 0;
    // once executed it returns your actual function.
    return function _refreshMediaAds() {
        if (mediaClickCounter < 2) {
            mediaClickCounter++;
        } else {
            mediaClickCounter = 0;
            refreshAds();
        }
    }
// you execute the function.
})();
```

Closures <3.

Comment: Gah, you got there before me.  Posted the same answer while I was typing mine... +1

Comment: Hi. Thank you for this. Worked great!! Can you explain this a little? I don't understand how there can be two refreshMediaAds functions. In debugging the first call var refreshMedia...seems to be overlooked. Just want to make sure I understand!! Thanks again.

Comment: the inner nested function shouldn't have a name, it should be anonymous.

Comment: @Endophage it can have a name if it wants. If your using a broken version of IE that falls apart for named function expressions then RRRRRRAAAAAAGGGGGGGEEEEEEEE. I made the name unique ;)

Comment: meh... I would still say it "shouldn't" (not can't) have a name.  No point in wasting a name on something that should just be anonymous...

Comment: @Endophage named anonymous functions are great for auto documenting code.

Comment: Named anonymous functions?! The whole world's gone mad.

Comment: @Town yes they have ;) I meant named function expression

Comment: @Raynos: I worked it out ;) The concept just made my head hurt! :)

Answer (score 2):

how about using something like this:

```
var ClickCounter = {
 mediaClickCounter: 0,

 refreshMediaAds:function() {
    if (this.mediaClickCounter < 2) {
        this.mediaClickCounter++;
    } else {
        this.mediaClickCounter = 0;
        refreshAds();
    }
 }
};
```

and then you can just use `ClickCounter.refreshMediaAds()` which will increment the member variable.

Comment: This is good solution. Also using eg. MooTools you can have additional features of OOP.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, you can create some object and use the function as its method. That way the variable will be object's property and not the global variable.

If you do not use any framework currently, using MooTools may help you a lot. Some examples for creating and using objects are located here: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class

Answer (score 0):

You can try returning what you have (so you can use it later if you want)

```
function refreshMediaAds(mediaClickCounter) {
    if (mediaClickCounter < 2) {
        mediaClickCounter++;
    } else {
        mediaClickCounter = 0;
        refreshAds();
    }
    return mediaClickCounter;
}
//then do: 
refreshMediaAds(clicks)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function refreshMediaAds() {
var mediaClickCounter = 0; // now variable have local scope.
    if (mediaClickCounter < 2) {
        mediaClickCounter++;
    } else {
        mediaClickCounter = 0;
        refreshAds();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that hits the spot. `mediaClickCounter` will be reset to `0` every time `refreshMediaAds` is called, so `refreshAds()` will never be called.

Comment: In this case, every time you call the function the mediaClickCounter gets reset to 0 though. Right?

Comment: Just saw your comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must, I believe something like this would do the trick.  However, IMO you should just leave it in the global namespace.

```
var refreshMediaAds = function() {
    var mediaClickCounter = 0;
    return function()
    {
        if (mediaClickCounter < 2) {
            mediaClickCounter++;
        } else {
            mediaClickCounter = 0;
            refreshAds();
        }
    }

}();
```

Note, I haven't tested this, it's an educated guess at a solution.

Comment: I thought global variables should be avoided. No?

Comment: @user699242 maybe if you're writing a script that will run on somebody else's site like jQuery.  If it's your own script running on your own site then it's not so much of an issue, you would only be screwing yourself if you later created a conflict.